# tab displays are screwed up, showing links instead of tabs

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
/div>
    <div class="profile_main_column column">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="profileTabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#newsfeed_div" aria-controls="newsfeed_div" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Newsfeed</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages_div" aria-controls="messages_div" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">

      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="newsfeed_div">
        <div class="posts_area"></div>
        <img id="loading" src="assets/images/icons/loading.gif">
      </div>


      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="messages_div">
        <?php  
        

          echo "<h4>You and <a href='" . $username ."'>" . $profile_user_obj->getFirstAndLastName() . "</a></h4><hr><br>";

          echo "<div class='loaded_messages' id='scroll_messages'>";
            echo $message_obj->getMessages($username);
          echo "</div>";
        ?>



        <div class="message_post">
          <form action="" method="POST">
              <textarea name='message_body' id='message_textarea' placeholder='Write your message ...'></textarea>
              <input type='submit' name='post_message' class='info' id='message_submit' value='Send'>
          </form>

        </div>

        <script>
          var div = document.getElementById("scroll_messages");
          div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
        </script>
      </div>


    </div>


  </div>
```

I don't understand why links are showing instead of tabs... can somebody help me figure out how to correct it? as I am new to bootstrap, I am struggling with it literally. The tabs don't work either. I have to select the newsfeed option to open that tab. even though I have given the active class in li item

[image: links showing instead of tabs]

Comment: You need to post your css

Comment: it's bootstrap 4

Comment: check with adding nav-item class to your li element

Comment: i have edited the code, even then it is showing the same links instead of tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing `class="nav-link"` inside `<a>` tags. Try this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="profileTabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#newsfeed_div" aria-controls="newsfeed_div" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Newsfeed</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link"  href="#messages_div" aria-controls="messages_div" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```